# Como remover um objeto de um array de objetos dentro de outro array de objetos, em javascript?

Tags: javascript, array, objetos, filter

Preciso retornar o array objs eliminando os objetos que possuem a key req === "teste" dentro do array de objetos c.

```js
const objs = [
  {
    a: "a",
    b: 1,
    c: [
      {
        send: "send",
        req: "req",
        res: "res"
      },
      {
        send: "send",
        req: "teste",
        res: "res"
      }
    ]
  },
  {
    a: "a",
    b: 2,
    c: [
      {
        send: "send",
        req: "req",
        res: "res"
      },
      {
        send: "send",
        req: "teste",
        res: "res"
      }
    ]
  }
];
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Primeiramente, você precisa estabelecer um esquema do que você deseja fazer:

- Você tem um `array` *(na resposta, chamarei esse `array` de <kbd>array principal</kbd>)*.
- Esse `array` tem vários objetos dentro.
- Esses objetos possuem uma propriedade `c`, que contém um `array` de objetos *(chamarei esses `array`s de <kbd>arrays secundário</kbd>)*.
- Desse último `array`, você deseja remover os objetos que tiverem a propriedade `req` com o valor `teste`.

---

Você pode resolver isso de diversas formas. Nessa resposta, abordaremos a solução usando os métodos [`map`](https://developer.mozilla.org/pt-BR/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map) e [`filter`](https://developer.mozilla.org/pt-BR/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter), ambos presentes no [`prototype`](https://developer.mozilla.org/pt-BR/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/prototype) de [`Array`](https://developer.mozilla.org/pt-BR/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array).

Como estamos mais interessados nos **objetos** presentes no <kbd>array principal</kbd>, vamos usar o método `map` para iterar sobre **cada** objeto desse <kbd>array principal</kbd>, realizando algumas mudanças. A partir dessas mudanças, o `map` retornará um **novo** `array`.

Dentro do escopo do *callback* do `map`, poderemos modificar cada objeto filho do <kbd>array principal</kbd>, podendo filtrar o `array` presente na propriedade `c`, usando o método `filter`.

Assim *(leia os comentários para um melhor entendimento)*:

```js
const objs = [{
  a: 'a',
  b: 1,
  c: [
    { send: 'send', req: 'req', res: 'res' },
    { send: 'send', req: 'teste', res: 'res' }
  ]
}, {
  a: 'a',
  b: 2,
  c: [
    { send: 'send', req: 'req', res: 'res' },
    { send: 'send', req: 'teste', res: 'res' }
  ]
}]

// Usando o método `map`, vamos iterar sobre cada objeto do array principal, de
// modo em que seremos capazes de modificar a propriedade (array) `c`, filtrando
// os objetos desse array secundário que possuirem a propriedade `req` definida
// como "teste":
const filteredObjs = objs.map((obj) => {
  // Modificamos somente a propriedade `c`, atribuindo a ela o array secundário
  // filtrado, sem os objetos que possuem `req` definido como "teste".
  //
  // O funcionamento é simples: quando retornamos `false`, o `filter` remove o
  // item da iteração atual. Quando `true` é retornado, o item é mantido.
  obj.c = obj.c.filter((childObj) => {
    if (childObj.req === 'teste') {
      // Retornaremos `false` somente quando `req` for definido como `teste`,
      // removendo esse objeto do array.
      return false
    }

    // Para todos os demais, retorne `true`, mantendo-os no array:
    return true
  })

  // Após filtrarmos a propriedade `c`, devemos retornar o objeto modificado
  // para o método `map`, caso contrário, ele irá criar um array de valores
  // `undefined`:
  return obj
})

console.log(filteredObjs)
```

Note que a resolução acima ficou muito verbosa. Fazendo uso completo dos novos recursos trazidos por versões **superiores** ao ES5, podemos reescrever a solução assim:

```js
const objs = [{
  a: 'a',
  b: 1,
  c: [
    { send: 'send', req: 'req', res: 'res' },
    { send: 'send', req: 'teste', res: 'res' }
  ]
}, {
  a: 'a',
  b: 2,
  c: [
    { send: 'send', req: 'req', res: 'res' },
    { send: 'send', req: 'teste', res: 'res' }
  ]
}]

const filteredObjs = objs.map((obj) => ({
  ...obj,
  c: obj.c.filter(({ req }) => req !== 'teste')
}))

console.log(filteredObjs)
```

Note que, para fins didáticos, é mais prudente que o **primeiro** excerto de código seja levado em conta.

---

> É importante ressaltar que, para uma boa compreensão dessa resposta, você esteja ligeiramente **familiarizado com o funcionamento** dos métodos [`map`](https://developer.mozilla.org/pt-BR/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map) e [`filter`](https://developer.mozilla.org/pt-BR/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter).

Comment: Cara, eu estava usando essa lógica de mapear e depois filtrar o elemento c, porém, estava me perdendo na lógica do retorno. Muito obrigado, ajudou de mais!

Comment: :)  Qualquer coisa, o melhor recurso é ir na documentação da MDN. A referência é completíssima!

Answer (score -1):

vc pode tentar remover o item utilizando a HoF .filter, que gera um novo array obedecendo sua condição.
algo como:

```
const filteredData = objs.map((obj) => obj.c.filter((objC) => objC.req !== 'teste'))

objs.map((obj) => obj.c = [filteredData])

console.log(objs)
```